# Limit products in CMS block

Tags: magento-1.8, static-block, cms-block

I try to limit the number of products shown in a static cms block as follows

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="4193" limit="4" mode="grid" template="catalog/product/list_custom_cat-grid.phtml"}}
```

I have tried others like

`num_products="4"` and `columnCount="4"` and some others but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I skipped through the source and did not see a way to pass in a *limit* property. Think about deriving your own block that respects that parameter.

There are also [approaches to modify the *Catalog New Products List* widget](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/22349) which comes pretty close to your requirements. But I guess the former is a little easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" category_id="4193"  mode="grid" template="catalog/product/list_custom_cat-grid_extra.phtml"}}
```

And then limit it in the pthml file.
So have a for while in the phtml